# RDF libraries for Scala

Tags: scala, rdf, libraries

I'm looking for a simple RDF library for Scala. So far I've found three, which all seem to have issues:

- scardf (https://code.google.com/p/scardf/) doesn't seem to be currently maintained, although it has documentation and positive comments
- banana-rdf (https://github.com/w3c/banana-rdf) seems to be actively maintained, but has no docs
- FeDeRate (https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/FeDeRate/summary) seems unmaintained and undocumented

Does anyone have any recommendations? I'm using Scala 2.10, and would like something light, fast and clean. I'm mostly going to be carrying out simple queries and storing stuff, but I'd like the option to work with external endpoints as well.

Comment: How about using FOSS Java library if there are no good scala ones?

Comment: A java library is a possiblity, but I'd rather find something in Scala so it integrates better with the rest of my code.